# How to pass some parmeters with a HTTP request which is sent to Tomcat WebApp?

Tags: http, tomcat, servlets, http-headers

I want to pass these parameters with a HTTP request to a WebApp hosted in Tomcat Container,
User Name, Password, The resource this request queries, What type a request is send

So is there a way to add these to HTTP header ? I heard that we can send the User Name and Password using HTTP Basic authentication way. Is there a way to send other parameters also ?

Comment: send these parameters as HTTP get or POST message.

Comment: No I want to add some values to the sending GET or Post method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make an with the Authorization header having the authentication details, such that further requests join the session and does not need authentication.

**Here is how to add Authorization header:**

**Create the header value.**

```
byte[] authBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("user:password".ToCharArray());
String authHeaderValue = "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(authBytes);
```

**Add the Authorization header with above value**

```
Authorization: authHeaderValue 

String webPage = "10.100.3.83:9764/example/servlets/servlet/…";; 
URL url = new   URL(webPage); 
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();    
urlConnection.addRequestProperty("Name","andunslg");   

//Username : andunslg
//Password : admin  
byte[] authBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("andunslg:admin".ToCharArray());
String authHeaderValue = "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(authBytes);

urlConnection.addRequestProperty("Authorization",authHeaderValue );
```

Comment: What is the way to add a header and what is the class I should use to send the HTTP request.

Comment: Which API are you using for making http connections.

Comment: I have no idea about what API should I use, but I have successfully added some headers using this code. Is it OK to use this implementation or is there any other good ways to do it ? String webPage = "http://10.100.3.83:9764/example/servlets/servlet/HelloWorldExample";
            URL url = new URL(webPage);
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.addRequestProperty("Name","andunslg");
            urlConnection.addRequestProperty("PW","admin");